# class selector affecting all elements

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create  a custom listbox to set selected value to the active textbox but instead it is changing  all the  textboxes (2 in my example).
My JQuery part :

```
$(".txtList").click(function(event) {
    var txtObj=$(this);     
    $("#lstSR").show();
    $("#lstSR TR").click(function(event) {
        var txtIndex =($(this).find('td:eq(0)').text() ); 
        txtObj.val($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text() );
        $("#lstSR").hide();
    });
});
```

My HTML part :

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<label for="txtList">My label</label>
<input type="text" name="txtList" class="txtList" />
<label for="txtList">My label 2</label>
<input type="text" name="txtList2" class="txtList" />
</form>
```

Comment: Why are your `$` wrapped in ` `$` ` ?

Comment: @PatsyIssa new users sometimes struggle with the code formatting.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the rest of the code was properly formatted, i was checking if it is from his actual code

Comment: @PatsyIssa very hard to believe as it would never execute and sounds like he got some code actually executing. Maybe he thought `$` is a special keyword needing its own code format, dunno.

Comment: On a sidenote, the `for` attribute of the `<label>` tag applies to element IDs, not classes. If it would apply to classes, it could possibly focus multiple input boxes, as it would in your code.

Comment: the user is defining a click handler inside a click handler. wow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding additional handler each time you click any of the textboxes, that's the reason it's "affecting all elements".

Without going into full code optimization, fix with minimal code change would be to simply unbind the click handler before binding new one:

```
("#lstSR TR").unbind("click").click(function(event) {
    //...
}
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/2BACX/).